# Drupal hide comment form in initial page load

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I'm using drupal 7 and want to hide my comment form for any content type to be hidden by default. I just need "Add comment" button, once i click on it, then it should render comment form. Is there any module / way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could hide the comment form in CSS with something like

```
#comment-form{display:none;}
```

plus a selector specific for one content type if you want.
Then add a javascript in that page adding some code to your subtheme's page.tpl.php that is in your subthem's templates folder (if there is no such file copy it from te parent theme templates folder)

```
 drupal_add_js('path_to_js_file/file.js');
```

And in the file.js you define the function to show/hide the comment form, i.e. to change the style of #comment-form to display:block;

Then you have to create the button and you can do this in several ways:
you can create a custom block with the code for the button, you can add it in the node.tpl.php template. You can add a custom field to the content type with Display Suite code field, or maybe other modules.

This is just one way to do it.

Comment: if ypu want to add the js only in some pages and not all you have to add a condition. Something like $node = menu_get_object('node',1); if($node->type === 'article') {drupal_add_js(...)}